# jQuery - issue with selecting which view to show based on screen size

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have implemented some jQuery in my rails app to change the nav items into a dropdown when the screen size is below 755px. I have it working 90%. I works when resizing and also for refresh. I have a problem when clicking any link, upon which it loads both views.

I found my current code here on StackOverflow. I suspect it has something to do with document.ready, but this is not my area of knowledge.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 755) {
    $("#web").hide();
    $("#mob").show();
  }
  else{
    $("#web").show();
    $("#mob").hide();
  }
});

$(window).load(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 755) {
    $("#web").hide();
    $("#mob").show();
  }
  else{
    $("#web").show();
    $("#mob").hide();
  }
});
```

I would like to have it load the proper nav when clicking on any link. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe offtopic but what about achieving this with css media rules?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Stephan Schrijver. I solved this with the following.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 754px) {
  .mob-nav {
    display: inline;
  } 
  .web-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 755px) {
  .mob-nav {
    display: none;
  } 
  .web-nav {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```